# Trouble with EditText in new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, android-edittext

I've got completely no idea why application is stopping unexpectedly when encounters commented lines in the code below.

```
public class Foo {
    private ExitText    input;

    public FooExitText input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void start() {

        // everything is okay:
            input.requestFocus();
            input.setOnKeyListener(new EntryCheckListener());
            input.setEnabled(false);

        // PROBLEMS!:   
            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (Foo.this) {


                    //  input.setEnabled(false);    

                        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
                            //input.setText("test" + i);
                        }

                    //  input.setEnabled(false);

                    }

                }
            });
    }
}
```

P.S.
What does it mean? :/

"Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: When you have application that crash like this, you really need to provide the output from logcat *:D, in particular the stacktrace. Without that and with the current level of information you are providing, its difficult for any of us to help.

Comment: I'm new to Android. Where can I find stacktrace logs? I use Eclipse IDE.

Comment: ok, if you are in eclipse, there should be a view under window -> show view called Logcat. In that view, you should be getting a bunch of red text that points out what you've broken :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify the UI from thread other then the main thread. Consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A nice tutorial can be found in the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).